# binary tree segment fail in c

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

Hi guys I am implementing a binary search tree in c. It seems insertion to tree works fine. But when searching, it gives a segmentation fail. Please review my code and give a reason for this issue and how to overcome it. Thanks in Advance.

following is the code....

```
struct node{
int data;
struct node *leftChild;
struct node *rightChild;
```

};

```
struct node *root=NULL;
void insert(int data){

struct node *current=NULL;

if(root==NULL){
    root=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    root->data=data;
    printf("Root data:%d\n",root->data);

}else{
    current=root;
    //Searching the posistion
    while(true){
        if((current->data)<data){
            current=current->rightChild;

        }else{
            current=current->leftChild;
        }
        if(current==NULL){
            break;
        }
    }
    struct node *tempData;
    tempData=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    tempData->data=data;
    tempData->leftChild=NULL;
    tempData->rightChild=NULL;
    current=tempData;
    printf("Current data:%d\n",current->data);

}
```

}

```
struct node* search(int data){
sstruct node *current=root;
if(current==NULL){
    return;
}else{

    while(current->data!=data){
        printf("%d",current->data);

        if((current->data)<data){
            current=current->rightChild;

        }else{
            current=current->leftChild;

        }
        //printf("Hello world!:%d\n",current->data);

        if(current==NULL){
            printf("%d",current->data);
            return NULL;
        }

    }
    return current;

}
```

}

And My main() method is....

```
insert(10);
insert(20);
insert(4);
insert(16);
search(20);
```

Comment: `if(current==NULL){
            printf("%d",current->data);
            return NULL;}` Maybe you'd like some time to think about this once more?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried a debugger already?

Comment: To overcome it, run it under a debugger ^^^^^^

Answer (score 1):

In your search function:

```
if (current==NULL){
   printf("%d",current->data);  //this is the place cause the seg fault. 
   return NULL;
}
```

current points to NULL, access the memory of a NULL place will cause the segmentation fault.

Comment: Yes and thanks for the point. But there is another problem. Search function is only working for the root data item. After that "current" will become NULL and terminates the loop. Expect an answer....
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is because you insert function didn't work properly. Please take a look at the following code:     struct node *tempData;
    tempData=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    tempData->data=data;
    tempData->leftChild=NULL;
    tempData->rightChild=NULL;
    current=tempData;
    printf("Current data:%d\n",current->data);  // The tempData then should become a left child node or right child node. You might want to have another node pointer variable to check the parent node. And then assign the tempData to the parent's left or right child pointer.